# R dplyr pivot wider with duplicates and generate variable names

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table, reshape, transpose

How can I go from

```
df<-data.frame(id=c("A", "B", "B"), res=c("one", "two", "three"))
df
```

to

```
df.output<-data.frame(id=c("A", "B"), res1=c("one", "two"), res2=c(NA, "three"))
df.output
```

with `dplyr`?

I do not know *a priori* the number of duplicates in `id` (in this example `B` has 2 occurrences), so the number of `resX` variables in the output data frame has to be generated on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create a row identifier, which you can do with `dplyr` and then use `tidyr::pivot_wider()` to generate all your `resX` variables.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    no = row_number()
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id,
    names_from = no,
    names_prefix = "res",
    values_from = res
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   id    res1  res2 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 A     one   <NA> 
#> 2 B     two   three
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table::dcast`:

```r
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), id ~ rowid(id, prefix = "res"), value.var = "res")

   id res1  res2
1:  A  one  <NA>
2:  B  two three
```

Answer (score 3):

A base R option with `reshape` + `ave`

```
reshape(
  transform(df, q = ave(id, id, FUN = seq_along)),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "id",
  timevar = "q"
)
```

gives

```
  id res.1 res.2
1  A   one  <NA>
2  B   two three
```

Answer (score 2):

A way with `pivot_wider`. Before we have to wrangle the data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(names = paste0("res", row_number())) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = names,
    values_from = res,
  )
```

```
  id    res1  res2 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     one   NA   
2 B     two   three
```